# Why can I not run DevExpress on Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, devexpress

Before installing Visual Studio 2015 on my PC, I have VS 2013 and on the that VS install DevExpress 15 and everything works fine.

But now when I install DevExpress on Visual Studio 2015, VS does not start project and stop project, what happens?

Comment: Did you check with DevExpress if they already support VS2015? Did the installation readme warn about any incompatibilities or issues? Have you contacted DevExpress support about this issue?

Comment: thanks to pay attention to my problem,okay check that.

Answer (score 0):

DevExpress only supports VS 2015 with version v15.1.6 and version v14.2.9.  All version of before either of these are not supported.

You can get full version support information from the following link:

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/versions.xml

Answer (score 0):

I just installed VS2015 and then ran the DX15.1 install - choosing this time to repair (see this site: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T246695 ).

DX15 is now available in my project, so I'm curious, what do you mean by: ".. VS does not start project and stop project,  ..."?

Is it not loading so you can work on the project?

My DX version: 15.1.10
My VS2015 version: 14.0.25123.00 Update2